# For Android's canvas, Is there a way to draw a path of variable width?

Tags: android, canvas, path

I have a path that I want to draw on the canvas, but I want to change the width of different sections depending on some variables. How can I do that?

Also, is it possible to use a bitmap pattern as the stroke of the path? Similar to what Photoshop has.

Comment: the Path object http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

Comment: Have you had any luck finding a way to do this in Android?